# Problem with updating background color of a JButton

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I have to maintain a very old and badly written Java software. And I ran into a problem after an update:

There are some buttons that change the shown panel in a card layout. There are handlers registered, and that part seems to work. Now the second part of these buttons is changing the background color. But this change is not triggered by the click. At least not directly. Clicking the button triggers a message to some machine, that machine then responds with a status, and that status then leads to a color change of that button.

This color change ceased to work after the last update. So basically there are 2 questions:

1. I have the vague idea that this lack of color changing is related to "do not update GUI elements outside the event dispatch thread". How probable is it that this is the root of the problem? There is an observation which leads to that assumption: Moving around the mouse triggers the color change after some time.
2. If yes, what would be the easiest way to cope with that? Implement a `PropertyChangeListener` on these buttons? Or any other (better) way?

Some code:

```
Color[] backgroundColors = {
    ColorExt.btnCol,                // 0 0 not prepare mode, not selected
    ColorExt.darkGreen,             // 0 1 not prepare mode, selected
    ColorExt.YELLOW,                // 1 0 prepare mode, not selected
    ColorExt.dimOrange,             // 1 1 prepare mode, selected
};
JButton[] btn = { mainframe.jBtnLoader1, mainframe.jBtnLoader2, mainframe.jBtnLoader3 };
for (int ldr=0; ldr<3; ldr++) {
    int colorIdx = 0;
    if ((inCellViewFromLoader[ldr][124] & 16) != 0) 
        colorIdx = 2;                   // bLoaderError = true => prepare
    if (mainframe.currentSelectedLoader == ldr) { 
        colorIdx += 1;                  // selected
    }
    btn[ldr].setBackground(backgroundColors[colorIdx]);
}
```

There is nothing special about it. This code itself is not the problem. My assumption is, since this code is executed in some network thread, not in the event dispatch thread, *that* is the root of the problem.

Comment: You are the only one that have the code. You are the only one to know how it work. You are the only one to know what is "the last update". We could play guess but that would be very long and unefficient

Comment: Sorry, but we basically can't help with such input. Yes, something in your code is wrong, and yes, it sounds like the code that triggers updates for your UI elements isn't doing it the right way. But the only real answer is: you have to study how these things work (probably by reading up large parts of https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/ ) ... then you have to debug your code. Nobody can remote diagnose and solve such things for you.

Comment: Sorry, posting the code here is not an option. There are 2 classes involved, each of them with about 6000 lines of code, nearly no comments.

Comment: Nobody suggests that you should put ALL your code here. If at all, you should create a [mcve]. That is why I told you that we cant help with such questions: the bug is in your code, and obviously you will not be able to show us all your legacy code and we actually would not want to see it either. This is a complex issue, and this community is simply not equipped (or meant!) to help with such requests.

Comment: The issue is complex indeed. I could present the relevant part of the code here, but there is nothing special with it. The code worked for years, and it still works here on my computer. It did not work at a customer installation in Japan.

Comment: Well, if there is nothing special, what's the problem debugging it?

Comment: Debugging it or simply running it always results in: It works. I can't debug it at the customer.

Comment: Use a `SwingWorker`; use `EventQueue.invokeLater` and perform the updates on the EDT

Comment: So to repeat the first question with other words: Is anybody here who ran into a similar problem? Updating a GUI element outside the event dispatch thread, that did not update that GUI element, only after moving around the mouse for some time? If yes, then this might be the problem. If not, i have to search for something different.

Comment: SwingWorker? EventQueue.invokeLater? That might solve this issue. I'll try that. Will take some time until we can install it at the customer again. But thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 1):

So, according to MadProgrammer's suggestion, I made a small utility class:

```
/**
 * Class to be instantiated in a call to EventQueue.invokeLater(), so the
 * background color of the given component is updated in the Event
 * Dispatch Thread.
 */
public class ColorChanger implements java.lang.Runnable {

private Color color = Color.WHITE;
private JComponent component = null;

public ColorChanger(JComponent component, Color color) {
    super();
    this.component = component;
    this.color = color;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    if (component != null) {
        component.setBackground(color);
    }
}
}
```

And then changed the line

```
btn[ldr].setBackground(backgroundColors[colorIdx]);
```

to:

```
EventQueue.invokeLater(new ColorChanger(btn[ldr], backgroundColors[colorIdx]));
```

At least that looks reasonable. It will take some time though until I can test this at the customer's site.

Comment: I'd just like to thank MadProgrammer for the idea. This kind of answer was what i hoped for.

Comment: Please 'tick' the answer (top left of the answer) to accept it and raise its visibility to future searches.